# jQuery Accordion - Don't want the entire parent li to be clikcable, just the link text

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have the following structure for my jQuery Accordion:

```
<ul id='accordion'>
    <li class='header'>
        <a href='#'>Click me</a>
    </li>
    <li class='content'>
        <div>blah blah</div>
    </li>
    <li class='header'>
        <a href='#'>Click me too</a>
    </li>
    <li class='content'>
        <div>blah blah</div>
    </li>
    <li class='header'>
        <a href='#'>Click me as well</a>
    </li>
    <li class='content'>
        <div>blah blah</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to put some other links in the header li, but the problem is, the entire li is clickable and activates the li below it. I just want the link text in the header li to be clickable. I have set the header as li.header, changing it to li.header a doesn't help. I've also tried disabling the accordion on init, then binding a function on clicking the link which 'activates' the content li by index.

```
jQuery('#accordion').accordion({
    header: 'li.header',
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    autoHeight: false
});

jQuery('li.header a').live('click', function(){
    var i = jQuery(this).parent().next().index();
    jQuery('#accordion').accordion('activate', i);
});
```

I hope I'm clear with my question! Or advice me if I should code my own accordion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the UI it would work like:

### *[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TumRT/)*

jQuery (no UI)

```
$('#accordion li.content').hide();


$('li.header > a').on('click',function(){
    var nxt = $(this).parent('li').next('li.content');
    
    nxt.is(':hidden') ? ($('#accordion > li.content').slideUp() , nxt.slideDown()) : nxt.slideUp() ;
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is cool... Let me try it out... But I would still like to know the answer for my question as I looked up on the net and seems like a lot of people face this issue!

Comment: If you want it in a more readable version (JS error free) here is a demo with `if else` statements: http://jsfiddle.net/TumRT/1/

Comment: Great, let me know the results!

Comment: Your code works fine, I'm using it. Saved me from coding a new one! +1 for you, but like I said, I'm waiting for the solution to do this with UI Accordion! A lot of people need the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the +1 (tought, adding the (almost) whole UI lib. for just an accordion... :) )

Comment: Hehe... you're right at that! Why use the library when you can code it, but I guess not all think the same, and not all can code the same way ;)

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna hafta mark this as accepted cuz no one else is looking up the question! Thanks mate :D

Comment: @RutwickGangurde I have tried to find an appropriate answer but with no luck, even tried a workaround my self. Thanks for remembering on me :)

Answer (score 0):

I ll just disable event propagation on other links except acccordion toggle link

check the demo  [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UHQB8/1/)

Comment: yes `li` will be click-able but links will not toggle accordion except the first link

Comment: Yes... I've already tried stopping the event propagation, doesn't work!

Comment: And the links in my content part already work fine without disabling the event propagation, but I want to do this for the header.

Comment: check the example, links are not in the CONTENT , they are in HEADER ,and this is just example to give you an idea , I hope this will help you , thanks